# Magento 2.4: Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogRuleSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogRuleSampleData

Tags: magento2

Getting the below error while trying to install sample data and upgrading the setup in Magento 2.4.2-p1
Error: `Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogRuleSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogRuleSampleData for module Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData`. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error(s) are existed in the following sample csv files.

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data/fixtures/catalog_rules.csv
/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data/fixtures/sales_rules.csv
```

2 solutions for the above issue:

1. Fix and validate the above CSVs manually or online tool like https://csvlint.io/
2. Comment line of code, calling above CSVs

   ```
   \Magento\CatalogRuleSampleData\Setup\Installer.php
   \Magento\SalesRuleSampleData\Setup\Installer.php

   like:
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function install()
       {
           //$this->rule->install(['Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData::fixtures/catalog_rules.csv']);
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Amazing how such a critical error can be published in the project

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error and invested four days rectifying it.

I also tried the above solution, i.e., commenting the line under install function from catalogue rule sample data and sales rule sample data. It too worked, but only temporarily. Because after following the above procedure, you cannot see the products from your Magento homepage, just banners only visible to you.

The real problem is that there is no sufficient space to deploy the sample data. Clear more than 4GB of space on your system and try it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct permissions for `var/ pub/ & generated/` directories

after above, your error will be vanished on `setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, on a Mac, with ElasticSearch installed through homebrew.

Before this error, I always saw the following errors in the var/log/system.log:

```
[2023-05-04T12:35:33.520048+00:00] report.ERROR: Sample Data error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [acom246_product_1_v1] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [acom246_product_1_v1] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"},"status":429} [] []
```

The `disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark` error occurred when I still have 897 GB of available disk space.
This resolved my issue:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "90%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "95%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "97%"
  }
}
'
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/*/_settings?expand_wildcards=all&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
'
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/fix-common-cluster-issues.html

Answer (score -3):

I had such a problem and recovered by running the command:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:remove
```

After upgrading, just run normally.